# Aprendiz de C (Fatoração em C)

Tags: c

Galera alguém pode me ajuda na lógica desse código ? o começo dele eu entendo mas fico meio atrapalhado na parte do for, alguém pode me ajudar a entender ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int fatorial, n;
printf("insira o numero que vc quer fatorar\n");
scanf("%i",&n);

for(fatorial=1;n>=1; n--){
    fatorial *= n;

}
printf("o fator do seu numero e: %i",fatorial);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você testou esse código?

Comment: sim sim testei.

Answer (score 3):

Sabendo que a fatoração é a multiplicação de um número por todos os seus números positivos menores que ele. Por exemplo: Fatorial de 5 = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = > 120

Então:

A cada iteração no loop, o número escolhido (n) é multiplicado pelo antecessor dele (n-1)

```
for(fatorial=1;n>=1; n--){
    fatorial = fatorial * n;

}
```

talvez assim dê pra entender um pouco melhor.

```
iteração 1: fatorial = 1 * 5; (fatorial vale 5)
iteração 2: fatorial = 5 * 4; (fatorial vale 20)
iteração 3: fatorial = 20 * 3; (fatorial vale 60)
iteração 4: fatorial = 60 * 2; (fatorial vale 120)
iteração 5: fatorial = 120 * 1; (fatorial vale 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ele esta iniciando um fatorial em 1 e vai até o **n** (informado pelo usuário)

E a cada interação ele vai multiplicar o **fatorial** (inicia = 1) pelo **n**, o `*=` faz o mesmo que `fatorial = fatorial * n`

Existem outras maneiras de calcular o fatorial, por exemplo utilizando essa bem simples com um laço `while`.

```
unsigned long long fatorial( int n )
{
    unsigned long long f = 1;

    while( n > 0 )
        f *= n--;

    return f;
}
```

Ou essa que talvez seja um pouco mais complicada de entender pois é recursiva.

```
long long fatorial(int n){
long long fat;
if ( n <= 1 )
    return (1);
else{
   return n * fatorial(n - 1);
}
}
```